# Finding a basis and dimension for a symmetric matrices subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

***Question:***

> Let $\mathbb{F}$ be $\mathbb{Z}_7$. Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}
> 2 & 5\\
> 5 & 3
> \end{bmatrix} \in M_{2\times 2}( F)$.
>
> Let $W=\left\{B\in M_{2\times 2}( F)\Bigl|( AB)^{t} =AB\right\}$ be a subspace over $\mathbb{F}$.
>
> Find a basis and a dimension for $W$.

---

***My attempt:***

$Solution.$

$\text{By the given information we have the following: }$
\begin{gather*}
AB=\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 5\\
5 & 3
\end{bmatrix} \cdotp \begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}
2a+5c & 2b+5d\\
5a+3c & 5b+3d
\end{bmatrix}\\
\end{gather*}
\begin{gather*}
AB^{t} =\begin{bmatrix}
2a+5c & 5a+3c\\
2b+5d & 5b+3d
\end{bmatrix}\\
\end{gather*}
$\text{By W's condition we get:}$

\begin{gather*}
AB^{t} =AB\Longrightarrow \begin{bmatrix}
2a+5c & 5a+3c\\
2b+5d & 5b+3d
\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}
2a+5c & 2b+5d\\
5a+3c & 5b+3d
\end{bmatrix}\\
\\
\Longrightarrow 2b+5d=5a+3c\\
\\
\Longrightarrow d=\frac{5a+3c-2b}{5} =a+\frac{3c-2b}{5} =a+\frac{3c+\overbrace{7c}^{0} -2b+\overbrace{7b}^{0}}{5} =a+2c+b
\end{gather*}
$\text{So $AB$ is depends on 3 free-parameters:}$
\begin{equation*}
 \begin{aligned}
AB=\begin{bmatrix}
2a+5c & 2b+5d\\
5a+3c & 5b+3d
\end{bmatrix} & & = & & \begin{bmatrix}
2a+5c & 5a+3c\\
5a+3c & 5b+3( a+2c+b)
\end{bmatrix}\\
 & &  & & \begin{bmatrix}
2a+5c & 5a+3c\\
5a+3c & 5b+3a+6c+3b
\end{bmatrix}\\
 & &  & & \begin{bmatrix}
2a+5c & 5a+3c\\
5a+3c & 8b+3a+6c
\end{bmatrix}\\
 & &  & & \begin{bmatrix}
2a+5c & 5a+3c\\
5a+3c & b+3a+6c
\end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
$\text{We take all the paramaters out of the marices, so we can get the basis vectors.}$

$\text{We get the following:}$

\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
2a+5c & 5a+3c\\
5a+3c & b+3a+6c
\end{bmatrix} =a\cdotp \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 5\\
5 & 3
\end{bmatrix} +b\cdotp \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix} +c\cdotp \begin{bmatrix}
5 & 3\\
3 & 6
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
$\text{Which isomorphic to the following vectors: }$
\begin{equation*}
( 2,5,5,3) ,( 0,0,1,0) ,( 5,3,3,6)
\end{equation*}
$\text{respectively.}$

$\text{Now, we shall check whether those vectors are linear independent. }$

\begin{gather*}
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 5 & 5 & 3\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
5 & 3 & 3 & 6
\end{bmatrix}\xrightarrow[ \begin{array}{l}
\mathcal{L}_{3} +\mathcal{L}_{1}\rightarrow \mathcal{L}_{3}\\
\end{array}]{}\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 5 & 5 & 3\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}\xrightarrow[\mathcal{L}_{1} -5\mathcal{L}_{3}\rightarrow \mathcal{L}_{1}]{}\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}\\
\\
\xrightarrow[ \begin{array}{l}
\frac{\mathcal{L}_{1}}{2}\rightarrow \mathcal{L}_{1}\\
\mathcal{L}_{3} -\mathcal{L}_{2}\rightarrow \mathcal{L}_{3}
\end{array}]{}\mathcal{\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}}\xrightarrow[\mathcal{L}_{3}\leftrightarrow \mathcal{L}_{2}]{}\mathcal{\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 2\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}}
\end{gather*}
$\text{Therefore, the vectors are linear independent, so they are basis of $\displaystyle W$,  }$ $\text{and since we have 3 linear independent vectors, we conclude that:}$
\begin{equation*}
\dim W=3
\end{equation*}

---

***Thoughts:***
Is what I wrote correct? or perhaps I missed something? I can't see if I am right or wrong, because I haven't solved questions of finding a basis for matrices subspaces. I will be glad for some help. Thank you!

Comment: That's incorrect. You have to see which vectors span $B$, not $AB$, as $B$ is the element of $W$

Comment: @ShubhamJohri ohhh you right :(, I thought $W$ contains all $AB$ for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's incorrect. You have to see which vectors span $B$, not $AB$, as $B$ is the element of $W$. So you have$$B=\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&a+b+2c\end{bmatrix}=a\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}+b\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}+c\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&2\end{bmatrix}$$You may check for linear independence of $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&2\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: thank you! as I wrote you in the last comment I thought $W$ contains all $AB$ which is clearly not true, so thank you :). I know how to progress from here, thank you really much!

Comment: You are welcome @Chopin